# How to generate State parameter to authenticate aws cognito google signup in reactjs without using amplify library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito

I have a nextjs app that use aws cognito for auth. I have to configured google login/signup in nextjs without using amplify as I am using vercel. I have generated the authentication url as follow

```
const googleLogin = () => {
   const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('https://abcstage.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse')
   const clientId = '<googleClientId>.apps.googleusercontent.com'
   const state = nanoid(); // auto generate by lib 
   const url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=openid%20email%20profile&state=${state}
   window.location.href = url
}
```

The state parameter generated but when I redirect to authenticate, it shows me the error as invalid state.

I have tried multiple solutions to create state parameter such as generating random string by using crypto, csrf, nanoid and some custom function, but the aws cognito returns the "invalid state" on screen

How do I create state to validate with aws cognito?

Thanks

Let me know if more info is required.